# How to find limit of the following fuction? $(2n)^yx^n$ as $n$ tends to infinity if $y \in (1, \infty)$ and $x \in (0, 1)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

How to find limit of following question?

Let $y \in (1,\infty)$ and $x \in (0,1)$.

Evaluate $(2n)^yx^n$ as $n$ tends to infinity?

Comment: sorry i cound'nt use latex as i am new to it and also sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: Take the natural logarithm of this expression.  Calculate the limit of that using rules of logs.  See what you learn.

Comment: This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Thank you for your advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have that by [ratio test](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/the-ratio-test-for-sequence-convergence)

$$\frac{(2n+2)^yx^{n+1}}{(2n)^yx^n}=x\left(1+\frac1n\right)^y \to x<1$$

therefore the sequence converges to zero.

Answer (score 0):

You may use L'Hopital's rule with $\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{2t}{(\frac1x)^{\frac ty}}=$ 
$\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{2}{((\frac1x)^{\frac ty})\cdot\frac{(-\ln x)}y}=0$.
So $\lim_{n\to\infty}(2n)^yx^n=0^y=0$.